# An algorithm to generate possible binary grid patterns

Tags: algorithms

This is my first question in this forum. I hope you will help me.

I was asked by a colleague to solve this puzzle. The puzzle goes like this:

I have an `m x n` grid where each cell can be in either of two states: **on** or **off**.

Initially the cells are in **off** state. I would like to have an algorithm that takes an integer input, `l`, and the grid, and gives me all the possible grid patterns where each pattern must have at least one **off-block**, where an **off-block** is a block of `l` contiguous cells all in **off** state.

**Constraints**:

1. There should not be a cell in an **off** state either before or after an **off-block**.
2. The **off-block** can be found not only in the vertical and horizontal orientation but also in the diagonal orientation.

The values of `m` and `n` can be as large as 32 and `l` is typically between 3 and 10 and it cannot be greater than either `m` or `n`.

**Examples**

Let's assume we have a `4 x 4` grid, let `l` be 3, `0` denote the **off** state and `1` denote the **on** state.

**Some valid patterns**

`|---|---|---|---| 
     | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
     | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
     | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 
     |---|---|---|---|` 

 has 3 **off-blocks**

`|---|---|---|---| 
     | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
     | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 
     |---|---|---|---|` 

 has 1 **off-block**

**Some invalid patterns**

`|---|---|---|---| 
     | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
     | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
     | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 
     |---|---|---|---|` 

 The main diagonal contains 4 (more than 3) contiguous cells in **off** state.

`|---|---|---|---| 
     | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
     | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
     | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 
     |---|---|---|---|` 

 Must contain at least one **off-block**

**My approaches**

These are what I have come up so far:

**First approach: Brute force**

My first approach was to list all the possible grid patterns and check each one of them if it satisfies the constraints. I immediately realized that this is not scalable. For instance, for a `4 x 4` grid I will have 2^16 possible grid patterns.

**Second approach:**
After each **off-block**, turn **on** the next cell. 
This procedure is repeated both in the horizontal and the vertical orientations.

Take for instance a `6 x 6` grid, let `l` be 3.

Initially, this is the grid:

`|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|`

Starting from the first row, turn **on** the the cell after each **off-block** along the **horizontal** orientation of each row and we get the following pattern:

`|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|`

Starting from the first column of the above grid, turn **on** the the cell after each **off-block** along the **vertical** orientation of each column and we get the following  pattern:

`|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|`

With this approach I can satisfy the first constraint. In order to get the other patterns I need to turn **on** the remaining **off** cells. The only option that I see is to adapt a brute force to deal with the remaining cells.

Moreover, turning a cell **on** may permit turning a neighbouring cell **off**, resulting in a valid new pattern.
For example from the following pattern where `l` is 2

`|---|---|---|---|
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
|---|---|---|---|`

we can get the pattern below by turning **on** the cell at coordinate(1,1) and turning **off** the cell at coordinate(2,2)

`|---|---|---|---|
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
|---|---|---|---|`

Therefore, even with the second approach I cannot gaurantee to produce all the possible patterns.

I hope the above the description is self-contained to understand the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What's the context where you ran across this problem?  I encourage you to cite the source of the problem.  Also, what approaches have you considered? What did you try, and where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: When you say "number of contiguous cells", do you mean "number of contiguous cells that are on"?  Finally... do you want to output a list of all such patterns?  Or just output a count of the number of such patterns?  Also, how large will typical values of n,m,l be?  Can you edit your question to address this feedback?

Comment: @D.W. I meant at most l contiguous off cells. Yes I want the list of patterns as the output. Typically, the values of n and m can be upto 32, but I could also have a larger grid.

Comment: A straightforward recursive procedure would do the trick very efficiently.

Comment: How large will typical values of l be?  What's the source where you saw this problem?  Please edit the question to incorporate all information into the question.  We want questions to be self-contained, so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion. I have edited my question. I believe it is better than the previous version.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Could you be more specific on the recursive approach? Thanks.

Comment: The recursive procedure gets a partially filled grid and a cell. It checks which values of the cell don't cause a bad pattern to form, and for each one, it recurses with the next cell.

Comment: Why have you rejected your second approach?  It seems like a plausible approach (except that you haven't described it in enough detail to show how that it generates all solutions; presumably you can't just take every `l`th cell, but need to consider a variety of possibilities).  Is there some requirement that it doesn't meet?  If so, what is the requirement that it violates?

Comment: @D.W. I have edited the question explaining the desired result and the contraints along with some examples and my approaches.

Comment: You present your question in a very complicated way. Is it true that you are looking for all $m\times n$ matrices in which the maximum number of contiguous 0s (horizontally, vertically, or diagonally) is exactly $\ell$?

Answer (score 1):

You want the set of grids that contains at least one contiguous off-block.

There is a simple iterative algorithm for this.  Enumerate the set of all locations and all orientations for the off-block.  For each such, fill in the grid with that off-block, and fill in the two squares on either end of the off-block per your first constraint; then the rest of the squares can be filled in arbitrarily, so enumerate all possibilities for them.

There will be exponentially many such filled-in grids, so this procedure will be computationally infeasible for all but the smallest grids.  Moreover, *every procedure* that correctly solves this problem will be computationally infeasible: the output (list of valid solutions) is exponentially long, so it will take exponentially long just to construct that output.  No amount of cleverness or algorithmic tricks will let you avoid this.  It is an inherent consequence of the problem statement.  The problem is simply not solvable (within any reasonable amount of time), except for small grids.

Comment: Initially, this is what I had in mind but, as you have noticed, this is not computationally feasible. I have implemented the solution suggested by @Yuval Filmus but running the program gave me a grid with all the cells set to **on** except the bottom right corner.

Comment: @Haileyesus, I edited my answer.  See the last paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You are right, since there are exponential many possible patterns, print each of them by itself is infeasible.

Comment: @Haileyesus I'm afraid you haven't implemented my algorithm properly. My implementation produces many answers.

Comment: Is it possible to send you the source file or at least the function?

Comment: @D.W. If I understand the OP's constraints correctly, then they disallow long off-blocks. It's not enough that one off-block has just the correct length, since there could be other off-blocks. Also, your algorithm enumerates some solutions more than once.

Comment: @Haileyesus You should try to understand the algorithm. That would help you to implement it correctly.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, that was my impression as well with the original version of the question, but the question has subsequently been edited and now it says just that the grid "must have at least one [long] off-block", but it doesn't appear to disallow other long off-blocks.  Note the "at least one".  I thought your answer was a good solution to the original version of the question.

Answer (score 0):

For an off-on matrix $M$, let $\ell(M)$ be the maximum contiguous run (horizontally, vertically, or diagonally, in both diagonal orientations) of off cells. You seem to be asking for the list of all $n\times m$ off-on matrices $M$ with $\ell(M) = \ell$.

One way to generate this list is using the following recursive procedure, which gets as input a *partially filled* off-on matrix $M$:

- If $M$ is complete filled, output it if $\ell(M) = \ell$.
- Otherwise, locate the first unfilled cell in $M$, set it on, and run the procedure recursively.
- Set the same cell to off, and check whether this introduces a contiguous run of off cells of length $\ell+1$. If it doesn't, run the procedure recursively.

Implementing the second step requires an ordering of the cells in the matrix. One possibility is to order the cells top to bottom and left to right.

You run the entire procedure with the empty matrix as input, and then it prints all legal matrices.

In practice I expect this procedure to be quite efficient, since (1) it seems that most of the time a choice which doesn't lead to an immediate run corresponds to a partially filled matrix which can be completed to a legal completely filled matrix, and (2) it seems that most matrices with $\ell(M) \leq \ell$ actually satisfy $\ell(M) = \ell$.

You can test this empirically by comparing the number of generated matrices to the number of recursive calls (divided by $nm$).

Comment: I have few doubts. What do you mean by 'completely filled' matrix? Is it a matrix with all 0s or all 1s or a matrix that satisfies the constraints?

Comment: A matrix with all offs and ons.

Comment: If  l < min(m, n), then a complete matrix in the first step will never satisfy the condition "L(M) == l"; hence, no output to print. Moreover, the next steps will make the matrix always incomplete.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can program this algorithm and see that it works. I forgot to mention that you have to start it with the empty matrix.

Comment: Yes, that's basically it, up to some simple optimization.

Comment: Alright, I will implement it with M initialized to all 0s.

Comment: No, that won't work. You have to implement it with M initialized to all "nothing"s.

Comment: I didn't get it. What does it mean to initialize to all "nothing's"? The values in the matrix are binary values. If not what is the point of checking "L(M) == l" on a completely filled M(that contains all "nothings")?

Comment: The entries of M have three different values: 0, 1, and "unfilled". You have to initialize all entries of M as "unfilled". Otherwise the recursive procedure would immediately stop.